# how to write recipe for the makefile in yocto

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

I am trying to add this package called [sane-airscan](https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan/blob/master/Makefile) to my yocto build. My experience with yocto is very basic.I do not know how to write a recipe for this one

This is the MakeFile for the above mentioned one

```
# USER-SETTABLE VARIABLES
#
# The following variables can be overridden by user (i.e.,
# make install DESTDIR=/tmp/xxx):
#
#   Name     Default                  Description
#   ----     -------                  -----------
#   DESTDIR                           Destination directory for make install
#   PREFIX                        Non-standard: appended to DESTDIR
#   CC       gcc                      C compiler
#   CPPFLAGS                          C preprocessor flags
#   CFLAGS   -O2 -g -W -Wall -Werror  C compiler flags
#   LDFLAGS                           Linker flags
#   COMPRESS gzip                     Program to compress man page, or ""
#   MANDIR   /usr/share/man/          Where to install man page

CC  = gcc
COMPRESS = gzip
CFLAGS  = -O2 -g -W -Wall -Werror
MANDIR  = /usr/share/man/
PKG_CONFIG = /usr/bin/pkg-config

# These variables are not intended to be user-settable
OBJDIR  = objs/
BINDIR = /usr/bin
CONFDIR = /etc/sane.d
LIBDIR := $(shell $(PKG_CONFIG) --variable=libdir sane-backends)
BACKEND = libsane-airscan.so.1
DISCOVER = airscan-discover
LIBAIRSCAN = $(OBJDIR)/libairscan.a
MAN_DISCOVER = $(DISCOVER).1
MAN_DISCOVER_TITLE = "SANE Scanner Access Now Easy"
MAN_BACKEND = sane-airscan.5
MAN_BACKEND_TITLE = "AirScan (eSCL) and WSD SANE backend"
DEPENDS := avahi-client avahi-glib libjpeg libsoup-2.4 libxml-2.0
DEPENDS += libpng

# Sources and object files
SRC = $(wildcard airscan-*.c) sane_strstatus.c
OBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(SRC:.c=.o))

# Obtain CFLAGS and LDFLAGS for dependencies
airscan_CFLAGS  = $(CFLAGS)
airscan_CFLAGS += -fPIC
airscan_CFLAGS += $(foreach lib, $(DEPENDS), $(shell pkg-config --cflags $(lib)))

airscan_LIBS := $(foreach lib, $(DEPENDS), $(shell pkg-config --libs $(lib))) -lm

airscan_LDFLAGS = $(LDFLAGS)
airscan_LDFLAGS += $(airscan_LIBS)
airscan_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--version-script=airscan.sym

# This magic is a workaround for libsoup bug.
#
# We are linked against libsoup. If SANE backend goes unloaded
# from the memory, all libraries it is linked against also will
# be unloaded (unless main program uses them directly).
#
# Libsoup, unfortunately, doesn't unload correctly, leaving its
# types registered in GLIB. Which sooner or later leads program to
# crash
#
# The workaround is to prevent our backend's shared object from being
# unloaded when not longer in use, and these magical options do it
# by adding NODELETE flag to the resulting ELF shared object
airscan_LDFLAGS += -Wl,-z,nodelete

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.c Makefile airscan.h
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CPPFLAGS) $(airscan_CFLAGS)

.PHONY: all clean install man

all:    tags $(BACKEND) $(DISCOVER) test test-decode

tags: $(SRC) airscan.h test.c test-decode.c
    -ctags -R .

$(BACKEND): $(OBJDIR)airscan.o $(LIBAIRSCAN) airscan.sym
    $(CC) -o $(BACKEND) -shared $(OBJDIR)/airscan.o $(LIBAIRSCAN) $(airscan_LDFLAGS)

$(DISCOVER): $(OBJDIR)discover.o $(LIBAIRSCAN)
     $(CC) -o $(DISCOVER) discover.c $(CPPFLAGS) $(airscan_CFLAGS) $(LIBAIRSCAN) $(airscan_LIBS) -fPIE

$(LIBAIRSCAN): $(OBJ) Makefile
    ar cru $(LIBAIRSCAN) $(OBJ)

install: all
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)$(BINDIR)
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)$(CONFDIR)
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)$(CONFDIR)/dll.d
    install -s -D -t $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)$(BINDIR) $(DISCOVER)
    cp -n airscan.conf $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)$(CONFDIR)
    cp -n dll.conf $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)$(CONFDIR)/dll.d/airscan
    install -s -D -t $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)$(LIBDIR)/sane $(BACKEND)
    mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/$(MANDIR)/man5
    install -m 644 -D -t $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)$(MANDIR)/man1 $(MAN_DISCOVER)
    install -m 644 -D -t $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)$(MANDIR)/man5 $(MAN_BACKEND)
    [ "$(COMPRESS)" = "" ] || $(COMPRESS) -f $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)$(MANDIR)/man1/$(MAN_DISCOVER)
    [ "$(COMPRESS)" = "" ] || $(COMPRESS) -f $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)$(MANDIR)/man5/$(MAN_BACKEND)

clean:
    rm -f test $(BACKEND) tags
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)

man: $(MAN_DISCOVER) $(MAN_BACKEND)

$(MAN_DISCOVER): $(MAN_DISCOVER).md
    ronn --roff --manual=$(MAN_DISCOVER_TITLE) $(MAN_DISCOVER).md

$(MAN_BACKEND): $(MAN_BACKEND).md
    ronn --roff --manual=$(MAN_BACKEND_TITLE) $(MAN_BACKEND).md

test:   $(BACKEND) test.c
    $(CC) -o test test.c $(BACKEND) -Wl,-rpath . ${airscan_CFLAGS}

test-decode: test-decode.c $(LIBAIRSCAN)
     $(CC) -o test-decode test-decode.c $(CPPFLAGS) $(airscan_CFLAGS) $(LIBAIRSCAN) $(airscan_LIBS)
```

I tried generating recipe using devtool but not success with it. Can anybody help me write a recipe for this one. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not a Makefile guru, but I usually create a patch to replace `CFLAGS  = -O2 -g -W -Wall -Werror` by `CFLAGS  ?= -O2 -g -W -Wall -Werror` and so one, so Yocto can override variables value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the sane-airscan author :-), but I don't know anything about yocto. So, what is your problem?

Comment: Yocto is a build tool to create applications for embedded systems. I have no problem building this package on the Linux but I am facing the difficulties to build this package using yocto for my embedded application

Comment: Can you provide more detailed explanations of problems which you have experienced while building with yocto?